# angular material table all the column names are put into same column

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I created an angular material table, all the values are displayed but the column headers are put into the same column. As you can see the "var1""var2""var3" are column titles. All of them are put into the first column. Is there any way to put each of them into different column they belong to?
[image]
I'm not sure what I missed in html or typescript.

The following is my typescript code:

```
import {
  Component, OnInit, ViewChild
} from '@angular/core';
import {MatTable, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatPaginator} from "@angular/material/paginator";
import {MatDialog} from "@angular/material/dialog";
import {NewPageDialogComponent} from "./new-page-dialog/new-page-dialog.component";
import {RestrictionInformation} from "../../models/restriction-information";
import {SampleData} from "../../models/sample-data"
import {NewPageService} from "../../services/new-page/new-page.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-page',
  templateUrl: './new-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-page.component.css']
})

export class NewPageComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3'];

  data: SampleData[] = [{
    var1 : "value1",
    var2 : "value2",
    var3 : "value3"
  }, {
    var1 : "value4",
    var2 : "value5",
    var3 : "value6",
  }]

  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<SampleData> = new MatTableDataSource<SampleData>(this.data);

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private NewPageService: NewPageService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<SampleData>(this.data)
  }

  @ViewChild(MatTable) table!: MatTable<SampleData>;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;

  onAddRestriction() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(NewPageDialogComponent, {
      width: '40%',
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(input => {
      if (input) {
        this.NewPageService.addRestriction(input)
      }
    });

  }

}
```

The following is my html:

```
<div>
  <h2>vin group criteria / rpo restriction criteria</h2>
  <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
      <!-- var1 Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="var1">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> var1 </mat-header-cell>
        <td *matCellDef="let SampleData" mat-cell> {{SampleData.var1}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="var2">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> var2 </mat-header-cell>
        <td *matCellDef="let SampleData" mat-cell> {{SampleData.var2}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="var3">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> var3 </mat-header-cell>
        <td *matCellDef="let SampleData" mat-cell> {{SampleData.var3}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns" mat-header-row></tr>
      <tr *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" mat-row></tr>
    </table>

    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 30, 60, 100]" aria-label="Select page of users"></mat-paginator>

  </div>
  <!-- br -->
  <div class="add-button-container">
    <button color="primary" mat-raised-button (click)="onAddRestriction()">
      Add Restriction
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The following is my css:

```
table {
  width: 80%;
}

.mat-cell {
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
}

.mat-form-field {
  width: 100%;
}

.mat-column-actions {
  width: 10%;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

td.mat-cell, th.mat-sort-header {
  padding: 16px 16px;
}

mat-header-cell, mat-cell {
  justify-content: center;
}

.example-list {
  width: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  min-height: 60px;
  display: block;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.example-box {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: move;
  background: white;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.cdk-drag-preview {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
  0 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
  0 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.cdk-drag-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
}

.cdk-drag-animating {
  transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

.example-box:last-child {
  border: none;
}

.example-list.cdk-drop-list-dragging .example-box:not(.cdk-drag-placeholder) {
  transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
}
```

Comment: provide a reproducable stackblitz link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all your

```
 <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> --header name here--- </mat-header-cell>
```

with

```
 <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> --header name here--- </th>
```

if you want to use `mat-header-cell` as an element you have to use
`mat-cell` instead of `td` and `mat-table` instead of `table`

https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#tables-with-display-flex

Comment: Thanks for point it out! I'll test these changes once the hashicorp vault is updated in our team

Comment: Solved! Thanks. Those values not stay in the same column now

Comment: May I ask you a follow up question please? I saw some examples only use <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> var2 </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let SampleData" > {{SampleData.var2}} </mat-cell> without using <th> and <td> and it still works. do you know why? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jUfEn032IL8 at 2:37:10

Comment: you have to use mat-table instead of table, mat-cell instead of td,etc. That's  what they did.